# Domesticate vs Domesticize

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, word-usage, differences

Is there a difference?

With animals, for instance: I feel like one refers to the taming of an individual. While the other refers to the adaptation of an entire (sub)species for integration with humans; via multiple generations of selective breeding.

Answer (score 1):

As defined by the [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/domesticize), "domesticize" is simply the transitive form of "domesticate". The two do not differ in meaning.
It also shows that "domesticize" is used less frequently than "domesticated".

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/domesticize) also simply gives the definition of **domesticize** as

> *tr.v.* To domesticate.